# driver.get on selenium giving error

Tags: python, selenium

I have tried running the following command after I've imported everything I need (selenium, webdriver, keys):

```
>>> driver.get('https://steemit.com/')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver.chrome' has no attribute 'get'
```

I can't find any solution.

Comment: Please show us all of your code. Otherwise we can't find a solution neither.

Comment: Can you successfully perform `driver.get('http://localhost:8000')`?

Comment: @DatHydroGuy nope...i get the same error

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call `.get()` method on a module. Instead, you need to *instantiate a webdriver*:

```
In [1]: from selenium import webdriver

In [2]: driver = webdriver.Chrome()

In [3]: driver.get('https://steemit.com/')

In [4]: print(driver.title)
Trending posts — Steemit
```

To avoid further `selenium` module usage confusion, please go through the ["Get Started"](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#getting-started) section of the Python/Selenium documentation.

Comment: >>> import selenium
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> from selenium.webdriver.common.key import Keys
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'selenium.webdriver.common.key'
>>> from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
>>> driver = webdriver.chrome
>>> driver.get('')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver.chrome' has no attribute 'get'

Answer (score 0):

from your comment it looks like your code is:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.chrome # should be webdriver.chrome()
driver.get('')
```

and your traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver.chrome' has no attribute 'get'
```

which you are missing the instantiation of the driver, also as pointed out below `chrome` should be capitalised, so this:

```
driver = webdriver.chrome
```

needs to become:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome() # the brackets mean the object is created or 'instantiated'
```

Comment: Looks like you're right @james-kent  Also, The word Chrome should have an uppercase _C_, as in: `driver = webdriver.Chrome()`

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "which you are missing the instantiation of the driver (see comment in code)"?

Comment: I capitalized the letter and it spewed out error messages

Comment: Post what you have tried and the output you get. `spews error messages` doesn't help us help you